# Equation for weighted average with normalization(?)

Tags: scales, weighted-mean, weighted-data, scale-construction

I am trying to understand how I should denote the equation for rescaling the following 7 categories into one value. The final weighted average is 0.57, which is possible by subtracting one and dividing by six. At least, this is normalizing right?

Thank you so much!

[image]

[image]